# QtQuick LocalStorage database version mismatch (missing "Version" attribute in ini file)

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am using QtQuick/QML/Qt5.2.1 on Android. I also tested this issue on the Desktop rather than Android and I see the same problem.

I use `LocalStorage` to persist application data after the application closes.

I open a database using `openDatabaseSync`:

```
var db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync(
    "TestDB",
    "1.0",  <-- version
    "Test Database",
    1000000,
    function(db) {
        createSchema(db);
        populateData(db);
    }
);
```

If the database does not exist and was created, the callback function gets executed and in that case I create the database schema and populate the initial dataset.

The next time the application starts, obviously I want to keep the database as-is and not recreate it.

The problem is when I restart the application I get this error:

```
Error: SQL: database version mismatch
```

If I inspect the .ini file that was created when the database was created the first time the application was run, I see this:

```
[General]
Description=Test Database
Driver=QSQLITE
EstimatedSize=1000000
Name=TestDB
Version=
```

You can clearly see a problem here is that the "Version" attribute is empty.

When the application starts up, it compares the requested version "1.0" against this empty string "" and fails.

I can fake it to get it to work of course by specifying the version as "", or by fixing the ini file - that at least tells me the code is otherwise correct - but clearly that's not a solution.

So, did I miss something or is this a Qt bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the database version after creating it:

```
var db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync(
    "TestDB",
    "1.0",
    "Test Database",
    1000000,
    function(db) {
        createSchema(db);
        populateData(db);
        db.changeVersion("", "1.0");
    }
);
```

Since the callback function will only be called it the database doesn't exists, and the changeVersion function will only work if current version is "" (otherwise, exception is thrown), I believe it's safe to use it.

EDIT: Maybe this is the intended behaviour... from [LocalStorage source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/7254e09442278f9e083a423c832c24b58e8fedec:src/imports/localstorage/plugin.cpp), line 700:

```
            if (dbcreationCallback)
                version = QString();
```

So, maybe you really need to set db version after you create your tables... before you do that on the callback, it's just an empty database, and shouldn't really have a version.

Comment: That seems reasonable, but it wasn't obvious at all from the documentation I found. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

set the attributes like this in your above code

```
 // db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync(identifier, version, description, estimated_size, callback(db))
     LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("kMusicplay", "0.1", "kMusicPlay app Ubuntu", 10000);
```

where
 'kMusicplay' is appname ,
 '0.1' is version , 
 'kMusicPlay app Ubuntu' is app discription 
  and '10000' is size of database